# How to point "latest" dist-tag to a previous version in npm?

Tags: npm

I have a published project with a few [dist-tags](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-dist-tag): "latest", "dev", and "beta".

I know how to bump the version by doing `npm version 2.4.7` or
`npm version patch` and I know how to add dist-tags with `npm dist-tag add <pkg>@<version> <tag>`, but how do I point the "latest" tag to a previous version?

Comment: I don't know if its possible. Anyway, why would you do this? Latest is latest, why poito not-latest?

Comment: @EliasSoares Well I know it's possible because it's actually an exercise for a nodeschool workshop. It specifically states that you have to change what "latest" points to back to a previous version to succeed. I can imagine scenarios where you might want to do this I guess, but the "why" is less important to me.

Comment: @EliasSoares I published a `4.0.0-alpha` thinking that the `-alpha` would make it not be what npm would install, because a pre-release is not a release. [I'm not the first to think this](https://medium.com/@mbostock/prereleases-and-npm-e778fc5e2420). Now I am trying to fix it by making `@latest` point back to the last published `3.X.Y` version without having to publish another `3.X+1.0` version with no changes.

Answer (score 26):

```
npm dist-tag add <pkg name>@<version> latest
```